# Android Java, how to get data from RoomDatabase into MainActivity

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

Apologies in advance for any mistakes, I'm new to this.
I'm trying to use RoomDatabase, and I'm trying to access data in MainActivity.
I inserted data into my table, and I have one entry that looks like this

sid : 1

name: myName

description: myDesc

I have three main files:

1. TaskDao.java
2. TaskViewModel.java
3. MainActivity.java

In TaskDao.java, I have this query (It's simplified for this exmaple):

```
@Query("SELECT 1 FROM task_table LIMIT 1")
int returnSid();
```

In TaskViewModel.java, I expanded on this:

```
public int returnSid()
{
    final int[] myInt = new int[1];
    TaskRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() ->
    {
        myInt[0] = taskDao.returnSid();
        Log.i("myLog", "myInt[0] showing as: " +myInt[0]);
    });

    return myInt[0];
}
```

In MainActivity.java, I have this code:

```
 int sid = mTaskViewModel.returnSid();
 Log.i("myLog", "In MainActivity, sid is: " +sid);
```

The log shows as:

```
myInt[0] showing as: 1
In MainActivity, sid is: 0
```

I think this is happening because I'm getting data from the database on a separate thread, and the threads aren't in sync. Any idea how I can fix this?
What is the best practice for getting data on the MainThread?
Thanks for your time and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You should either consider returning a `LiveData` or calling `allowMainThreadQueries()` on your database builder (not recommended)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Room doesn't even allow queries on the main thread, so I'm not quite sure how the query in your activity is running at all. Is there more code to it?

Comment: @GregorRant I tried with LiveData, but I was getting null in the MainActivity when I was trying to assign the sid. Maybe I'm not doing it right... Let me try again.

Comment: @HenryTwist This query isn't being done on the MainThread. TaskRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> 
does the SELECT query on a separate thread. I think that's where my issue is coming from. myInt[0] is getting the value on the separate thread, and the main thread is what's accessing myInt[0], giving it a wrong value since these threads aren't synced.

Comment: Sorry you're right. So when are you trying to access `myInt[0]` (on the main thread)?

Comment: MainActivity.java accesses it with the line:
int sid = mTaskViewModel.returnSid();

Comment: @GregorRant, isn't LiveData mostly used for when the database is updated? I'm not updating the database. I'm just using a SELECT statement. 

Also isn't LiveData mostly useful for seeing changes to the UI? I'm not trying to update the UI. I'm just trying to get a value using a SELECT statement. 

Or am I just completely wrong here?

Comment: Database access is asynchronous, so unless you're waiting somehow on the other end, you're going to get nothing back. That's why `LiveData` is used sometimes, not to listen for changing values, but to listen for a *single* value.

Comment: Otherwise you can just pass in a callback, which you can trigger when the data has loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231231/discussion-between-tim-and-henry-twist).

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution with `Runnable` is working for me. I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, so if someone could please demonstrate the best practice, I'd be grateful.

Task.java

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "sid")
public int sid;
```

TaskDao.java

```
@Query("SELECT sid FROM task_table WHERE name = :taskName")
int returnSid(String taskName);
```

TaskViewModel.java

```
public int returnSid(String taskName)
{
    int sid = taskDao.returnSid(taskName);
    return sid;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Runnable myRunnable = () ->
{
    try 
    {
        int sid = mTaskViewModel.returnSid(taskName);
        // Do rest of the work with sid here
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // Log exception
    }
};

Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
thread.start();
```